# How to get Android device serial no programmatically

Tags: android

I can see  serial number in my android device beneath of the battery in my android device(After removing the battery). 
Any help to retrieve this serial number ( not IMEI or device ID ) programmatically in android?

Comment: This is the SERIAL of android.os.Build Log.i("TAG","android.os.Build.SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);

Answer (score 1):

I think this may helps you

```
 String debug2 = System.getProperty("os.version");
            String debug3 = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
            String debug4 = android.os.Build.DEVICE; 
            String debug5 = android.os.Build.MODEL; 
            String debug6 = android.os.Build.PRODUCT; 
            String debug7 = android.os.Build.BRAND; 
            String debug8 = android.os.Build.DISPLAY; 
            String debug9 = android.os.Build.CPU_ABI; 
            String debug10 = android.os.Build.CPU_ABI2; 
            String debug11 = android.os.Build.UNKNOWN; 
            String debug12 = android.os.Build.HARDWARE;
            String debug13 = android.os.Build.ID; 
            String debug14 = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER; 
            String debug15 = android.os.Build.SERIAL; 
            String debug16 = android.os.Build.USER; 
            String debug17 = android.os.Build.HOST;
```

For more Info refer this [Article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

**OR**

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = null;
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String simSerialNo = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Comment: I cant see the android.os.Build.SERIAL ?is there anything else i need to get this?

Comment: IT is Added in API level 9 will not work for older versions